# Using tagName and className properties on Backbone View Vs using template

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a Backbone View that is using a Backbone Collection to pull data from an api:

```
var HousesView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {

    this.collection = new Houses();

    var that = this;
    this.collection.fetch({
      data: {
        pageSize: 50
      },
      success: function () {
        that.render();
      },
      error: function () {
        console.error('There was an error in fetch');
      }
    });
  },
  tagName: 'section',
  template: Handlebars.getTemplate('houses'),
  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template({ houses : this.collection.toJSON() }));

    return this;
  }
});
```

It then creates models from the json pulled from the api and passes that as a collection to my template which takes each model and for e.g.just outputs the name attribute of that model as a list. That works fine.

My question is: because I am using a template to parse the data from `this.collection.toJSON()` the `tagName` I set on `HouseView` doesn't seem to be output in the html. If I am using a template for a View does this mean properties like `tagName`, `className` etc wont be output?

Also, ideally I would like to create a `HouseView` for each model from the collection and then display all of those in a wrapper `HousesView`.

Comment: Are you adding the view's `el` to the page anywhere? Usually you'd do something like `some_element.append(house_view.render().el)`.

Comment: Show us how you're using `HousesView` in a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

In your example you are using custom rendered. In that case the auto generation of view from `tagName`, `className` and `id` will be spiked (overwrites by method `this.$el.html` in render function.).

The best approach is as you mentioned to create separate view and append it in render of main view to html.